# To get the selected rows form database table by entering a value in form

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

```
        PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from test where testname like '?%'");
        stmt.setString(1,keyword);
        rset=stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rset.next()){
            out.println(rset.getString(1));
            out.println(rset.getString(2));
            out.println(rset.getString(3));
            out.println(rset.getString(4));


        }
```

I am using tomcat as server and the exception is :
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

here i am enter testname in a form, and by using getParameter(); method assign this value to a string keyword.I want to use 'like' so that i can retrieve only selected Test name.

Comment: What does your database look like?

Comment: How many columns are there in the table? There should be at least 4 for `rset.getString(4)` to work.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark must not be in quotes.  Try this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(
    "select * from test where testname like concat(?, '%')");
```

Or, you could do it this way:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(
    "select * from test where testname like ?");
stmt.setString(1,keyword + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from test where testname  LIKE '%' || ? || '%' ");
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/502785/JDBC/databases/preparedstatement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a **?** in quote, it won't work. a simple workaround is to append the actual value in the query string.

```
String keyword = "parametervalue";
String query = "select * from test where testname like '" + keyword +"%'";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: This leaves you open to SQL injection. Better is to either put the `%` in the parameter value itself, or concatenate the parameter with it (eg `LIKE ? || '%'`)